# $C^{*}$-algebras generated by commuting normal elements?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

A person in my class asked today if $\mathfrak{A}$ is a unital $C^{*}$-algebra and $x,y \in \mathfrak{A}$ commute and are normal, then is it always the case there exists $\alpha \in C^{*}(x,1)$ and $\beta \in C^{*}(y,1)$ such that $C^{*}(x,y,1) = C^{*}(\alpha+\beta,1)$?

I don't think this could be true, as it would seem to insinuate that one could apply Gelfand theory to $C^{*}(x,y,1)$ so that $C^{*}(x,y,1) \hookrightarrow C(\text{sp}_{\mathfrak{A}}(\alpha+\beta))$ and moreover that: $$C^{*}(x,1), C^{*}(y,1) \hookrightarrow C(\text{sp}_{\mathfrak{A}}(\alpha+\beta)).$$  This doesn't seem right to me, as it then seems to imply everything we could know about both $x,y$ can be obtained by looking at some random sum of two elements from the $C^{*}$-algebra they generate.. Especially on the physics side of things, this seems wrong.

Perhaps I'm missing an obvious counter example or perhaps this is 'clearly' true?  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider $x$ and $y$ that are in tensor position and both with 2-d spectra. Then $C^\ast(x, y, 1)$ should have a 4-d spectrum, so it cannot be generated by a single element.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean here?  I'm not familiar with tensor position.

Comment: I just mean the algebra $A$ is the tensor product of $C^\ast(x, 1)$ and $C^\ast(y, 1)$. So like, let $T$ be the multiplication by identity map on $H = L^2(\mathbb{D})$. Then let $x = T \otimes Id$ and $y = Id \otimes T$, both acting on $H \otimes H$. Then because $C^\ast(x, y, 1) = C^\ast(x, 1) \otimes C^\ast(y, 1)$, the spectrum of $C^\ast(x, y, 1)$ is $\mathbb{D} \times \mathbb{D}$, which is 4-d. So $C^\ast(x, y, 1)$ cannot be isomorphic to $C^\ast(z, 1)$ for a single normal operator $z$ as the latter has spectrum contained in $\mathbb{C}$, per Invariance of Domain.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks.  It was nice seeing you at GOALS last year

Comment: Ah, were you also at GOALS last year? Sorry I couldn’t recognize you from your profile.